# GData Client library for picasa photo uploading

Tags: objective-c, gdata

I m getting the error when adding GData clientlibrary for photo uploading on Picasa
Error log is as follows

```
Ld /Users/Macintosh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhotoYaar-ftppukpwhpkripftssebcboomfcx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoYaar.app/PhotoYaar normal i386
cd "/Users/Macintosh/Desktop/Paras/Projects/Photo Yaary/01-02-2013/PhotoYar"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/Macintosh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhotoYaar-ftppukpwhpkripftssebcboomfcx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/Macintosh/Desktop/Paras/Projects/Photo Yaary/01-02-2013/PhotoYar/../../Data_Photo_App/GData-iOS-Static-Library-1.12-master" "-L/Users/Macintosh/Desktop/Paras/Projects/Photo Yaary/01-02-2013/PhotoYar/../../../../.." -F/Users/Macintosh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhotoYaar-ftppukpwhpkripftssebcboomfcx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-F/Users/Macintosh/Desktop/Paras/Projects/Photo Yaary/01-02-2013/PhotoYar" -filelist /Users/Macintosh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhotoYaar-ftppukpwhpkripftssebcboomfcx/Build/Intermediates/PhotoYaar.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoYaar.build/Objects-normal/i386/PhotoYaar.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -all_load -lxml2 -ObjC -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 /Users/Macintosh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhotoYaar-ftppukpwhpkripftssebcboomfcx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGPUImage.a -lGDataTouchStaticLib -framework Security -weak_library /Users/Macintosh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhotoYaar-ftppukpwhpkripftssebcboomfcx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GData/GData -lxml2 -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation -framework AddressBook -framework Accounts -framework CFNetwork -framework OpenAL -framework SystemConfiguration -lsqlite3.0 -framework ImageIO -framework CoreVideo -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMotion -framework MessageUI -framework Twitter -framework OpenGLES -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreImage -lz.1.1.3 -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/Macintosh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhotoYaar-ftppukpwhpkripftssebcboomfcx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhotoYaar.app/PhotoYaar

ld: file not found: /Users/Macintosh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PhotoYaar-ftppukpwhpkripftssebcboomfcx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GData/GData
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can i solve this?
i m using this url as a reference

```
 http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is that the linker is not finding the library to link against.

You'll need to fix your project so it can link to the library framework.  Linking details are [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary#Linking_to_the_Mac_OS_X_Framework).